# Visual Workflow Input Values

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm missing something obvious in Visual Workflow but I'm stumped.  Why do the values I enter in my Input Screen not display in my Output Screen?

Flow
[image]

Input Screen
[image]

Input values
[image]

Output Screen
[image]

Display Same values
[image]

Variable

[image]

Comment: I edited your images into the question as that is how the preferred format of questions works here.

Comment: Eric - for starters you have the bottom screen, display screen, as the starting screen and the 'input' screen as your finishing screen.  I think you maybe missed the order of screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eric - Adding a default value on another screen works just fine.  See my [video example](http://screencast.com/t/MKMZeJq7U86). From the screen shots I think your screen order is backwards.  You have your display as the start and input as the finish.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display the value of variables that will be collected via an input screen you need to put in an assignment step after the input screen, as in the example below. Without the explicit assignment the values will not be passed into the variables.

It is also possible to display the input values by making the default value for the output field the value of the input field, but if you want to repeatedly use the value then using variables is often easier as flow variables can have values passed in or out of the flow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Display of the input screen field value on the output screen.

[image: Output using input]

Comment: This example works but isn't correct statement.  You do not have to have an assignment in order to present the previous input value to another screen.  You can see this from my video: http://screencast.com/t/MKMZeJq7U86

Comment: I did say that the assignment was needed for variables, and showed how an input can be picked up in in output field